# Não consigo configurar o GIT remoto no servidor

Tags: git, git-remote

não consigo configurar o GIT para subir no servidor.

Inicializei o git localmente e configurei o GIT REMOTE (aparentemente) certo, seguindo alguns tutoriais encontrados na web.

No servidor, criei a pasta onde ficará os repositórios, a pasta do projeto (/repo/projeto.git) e após isso GIT INIT --BARE.

Setei a url deste projeto.git lá no GIT ADD REMOTE.

Entre vários testes, já aconteceram duas ocorrências:
1ª - Após o GIT PUSH ORIGIN MASTER, subiu tudo, deu tudo ok, mas no servidor não estavam os arquivos, ou seja, não subiu.
2ª -

```
fatal: '/repo/projeto.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Não sei mais como proceder para configurar corretamente o git no servidor. =/

Podem me auxiliar?

Answer (score 0):

No servidor remoto crie uma pasta para seu projeto e outra pasta para armazenar o git

```
mkdir myapp myapp.git
```

Entre cd `myapp.git` e inicie um repositório bare `git init --bare`

Clone o repositório para sua máquina local:

```
git clone ssh://myserver.com/webapps/myapp.git
```

Na sua máquina crie um arquivo .txt apenas para nível de teste:

```
touch teste.txt
```

Na sua máquina adicione o projeto ao git `git add .` e `git commit -m "Start Project"`

Atualize o repositório remoto `git push origin master`